# FATAL: Cannot find executable from the chosen Maven installation "Maven-2.2.1"

Tags: jenkins

While executing a Jenkins job, I am getting this error message and the build fails.

> FATAL: Cannot find executable from the chosen Maven installation "Maven-2.2.1"
>   Build step 'Invoke Top level Maven' marked build as failure

Please help me; what is the actual problem?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins misconfiguration. Contact your Jenkins administrator.

Comment: I configured the variable Maven-2.2.1 in master jenkins, and created a job on it, but the job was running on the slave. Is there any problem?

Comment: Well, if it runs, it runs... it's up to Jenkins to decide where it runs, unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: If the job runs on the slave, you need to install maven on the slave (or let jenkins install maven automatically)

Answer (score 0):

If it runs on the slave you must install maven on the slave PC. I'm really not sure but I think that you also need to set the maven version in the Jenkins configuration.